# laser_driver stack missing in pr2-desktop install

Tags: ros, installation, hokuyo-node, ros-diamondback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like the laser_drivers stack is missing from the pr2-desktop dimaondback install. Is this intentional?

Here is what I did -

> $ sudo apt-get install ros-diamondback-pr2-desktop

When I tried to roscd to hokuyo_node, I got an error.

> $ roscd hokuyo_node 
> roscd: No such package 'hokuyo_node'

Installing the laser_drivers stack fixed the problem:

> $ sudo apt-get install ros-diamondback-laser-drivers

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10154/laser_driver-stack-missing-in-pr2-desktop-install/) by [Advait Jain](https://answers.ros.org/users/219/advait-jain/) on ROS Answers with karma: 140 on 2011-06-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See [REP 108](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0108.html#desktop-variants) for which stacks are included in which variants. Note that, as specified there, laser_drivers is not included in pr2-desktop or any of the variants that it extends.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0